# Different results with scikit-learn v21 vs v22

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am an following a ML course which, when published, the versions of the used libraries were:

```
numpy 1.16.5

pandas 0.25.1

sys 3.7.4

sklearn 0.21.3
```

My versions instead of the corresponding libraries are:

```
numpy 1.18.1

pandas 1.0.1

sys 3.7.6

sklearn 0.22.1
```

Up to now, all the results published in the course coincide with the results obtained by me.

Now, however, despite using the same code and the same data, I get completely different results.

I think the problem might be related to the different versions of the used libraries. Perhaps, in the same functions used, there are parameters that take default values that did not 
affect the result at the time while in the current version they create problems.

Here is a minimal reproducible version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import sklearn


from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston_data = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston_data.data, columns=boston_data.feature_names)

y = boston_data.target

df = pd.read_csv('data//housing.data', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df.columns = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX',           'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV'   ]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

X = df.values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, criterion='mse', random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)

forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_pred = forest.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = forest.predict(X_test)

print('MSE train: {0:.4f}, test: {1:.4f}'.\
       format(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred),
       mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)))

print('R^2 train: {0:.4f}, test: {1:.4f}'.\
       format(r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred), 
       r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)))
```

I got results

```
MSE train: 0.0090, test: 0.0227

R^2 train: 0.9999, test: 0.9997
```

While in the course of ML the results were:

```
MSE train: 1.8700, test: 9.3921

R^2 train: 0.9787,  test: 0.8740
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Well, it must be the very first time that someone asks for help because they get **better** results than expected!

Comment: Irrelevant to your (non) issue, but it is puzzling why while you build a `df` from the built-in Boston data, you feel the need later to load the same dataset from the disk and assign it again to the same `df`...

Comment: This shows my ignorance in the matter. What I have reported is not my code but what is proposed in the course.Again due to my ignorance, I thought I had to get the same results. Not getting them I thought there was some mistake.

Comment: It does raise a question regarding the magnitude of the difference (which is indeed huge for the MSE), but don't loose your sleep over it - it is difficult to reproduce exactly, plus it pre-supposes a great amount of confidence on the results as reported by someone else (which is not a very good idea in principle). I kindly suggest you just delete this and move on.

Comment: On https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html there is a note that says that on version 0.20 they fixed a wrong datapoint. This does NOT match your question (v21 vs v22) but maybe some of the examples in your course were from an older version.